# How to resolve domain externally with bind9?

Tags: bind, resolve

## Preface

I am hosting a web server and DNS server on the same box over a home network. The external IP is dynamic. To handle this, I use a paid service called no-ip.com to automatically update the IP of mydnsserver.com (let's say external IP is 11.22.33.444). I want to use mydnsserver.com to resolve mywebsite.com (and any other websites later on) so that all external connections to mywebsite.com will be handled by Apache.

## Problem

The problem that I am having and can't find a solution to is that when I visit mywebsite.com on my phone (external connection), my browser resolves to localhost. I need the domain to resolve (both internal to the server and externally) to Apache running on mydnsserver.com so that the website will be rendered from my server. I want to do this without having to enter the IP address of the server for the A record.

## Registrar Settings (Godaddy)

**mywebsite.com nameserver settings**

```
ns.mydnsserver.com
ns2.mydnsserver.com
```

**mydnsserver.com nameserver settings**

```
ns1.no-ip.com
ns2.no-ip.com
ns3.no-ip.com
ns4.no-ip.com
ns5.no-ip.com
```

## Resolve Config

**/etc/resolve.conf**

```
domain mywebsite.com
search mywebsite.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

## Bind9 Config

**/etc/bind/named.conf**

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
};
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones**

```
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};

zone "mywebsite.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/mywebsite.zone";
};

zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

**/etc/bind/zones/mywebsite.zone**

```
$TTL 1d
@       IN      SOA     mywebsite.com. root.mywebsite.com. (
                       2014112501   ; serial#
                       1h           ; refresh, seconds
                       1h           ; retry, seconds
                       1h           ; expire, seconds
                       1h )         ; minimum, seconds

@               IN      NS      mywebsite.com.
@               IN      A       127.0.0.1
@               IN      MX 0    mail.mywebsite.com.
www     IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

## nslookup

**mywebsite.com**

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   mywebsite.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

**mydnsserver.com**

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mydnsserver.com
Address: 11.22.33.444
```

Is what I am doing is not possible? Do I -have- to use the real IP address to resolve to? It looks like what it's doing is taking exactly what I enter into the Zone File, and setting any browser to exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the zone file out of /etc/bind/zones and updating the named.conf.default to look for zones in the new location fixed the issue.