# graph.facebook.com API no route to host for IPv6

Tags: php, facebook

Steps required to reproduce the problem
I have post the article data and it returns error.
Expected Result
Success
Actual Result
array(1) { ["error"]=> string(58) "Failed connect to graph.facebook.com:443; No route to host"

```
$news_content = $this->format_content($news_param->articls);
        $transformer->transformString($instant_article, $news_content, 'utf-8');
        try {
            $status['success'] = $ia_client->importArticle($instant_article, $is_published);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $status['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
```

and facebook instant article using: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php

Reply from Dig:

```
sh-4.2# dig graph.facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-50.el7_3.1 <<>> graph.facebook.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60775
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;graph.facebook.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
graph.facebook.com.     604800  IN      A       173.25.5.11

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.                    604800  IN      NS      .

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 12 18:49:28 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76
```

I think I should mention that this is running on a docker LAMP stack.

Comment: Do `dig graph.facebook.com` from the server. Does it work?

Comment: question updated with dig output

Comment: `173.25.5.11` is owned by `Mediacom Communications Corp`, not Facebook. Looks like your ISP is MITMing you.

Comment: well, that's a wildcard ip for the bind dns server running in a separate container.

Comment: `dig graph.facebook.com` *should* be giving you the IP address (or several) of Facebook's API servers. Why would it be returning its own IP in response to an `A` record request?

Comment: Yeah but every hostname I am trying to dig, it shows up the internal ip of the server. I tried ns1.hostgator.com but still the same result. where I might be going wrong with the bind dns?

Comment: It sounds like your bind server is misconfigured. I'd guess you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137100/how-to-resolve-domain-externally-with-bind9 but I always outsource DNS management.

Comment: What does IPv6 have to do with it? Your title says IPv6, but nothing in your question indicates that as a problem.

Comment: It seems to be related to ipv6 because sometimes it worked when I tried to curl the graph.facebook.com. So, my assumption was it might be the curl trying to query ipv6 from the url instead of ipv4. Is there any php.ini configuration for disabling ipv6 from the curl extension?

Answer (score 0):

I have stopped the bind server and redirected all dns traffic to google dns. Now everything is working fine. Anyways, thank you guys for the suggestions.